# How to embed dynamic html safely in a dynamic javascript file so that it doesn't break the javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, escaping

I need to build a javascript file on the fly and embed some html inside it, so that when run, the  javascript will be able to add the html to the DOM.

I hava a javascript.js that I can interpolate using wicket. It contains:

```
var html = "${somehtml}"

document.write(html);
```

At the moment, if I replace the `${somehtml}` with html that contains single quotes, it will obviously break the html.

I tried using `URLEncoder.encode()` and javascript `unescape()` but this broke the javascript.

I'm wondering if I can encode/decode to/from base64? Or is there a another solution?

Comment: String(Base64.encodeBase64(html.getBytes())) worked but required a fair bit of javascript to decode. Good though if you want to obfuscate your html. StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(html) was neater though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons provides a helper class called [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html). It can encode strings so that they can be safely embedded in javascript (ecmascript).

Answer (score 1):

First replace every backslash with two backslashes, then replace every quote with a backslash and a quote. Something like

```
var newstring = mystring.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\").replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is what you're looking for because you're building the js on the fly but embedded javascript files (*.ejs) allow you to load markup from an external file *(with the option to pass custom data in too)* rather than putting everything in quotes and looking generally messy.

It's at least useful for development, but I'd rather not have to send more files to the client.

http://embeddedjs.com/

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

versus

```
someVar += "<ul>";
for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {
    someVar += "<li>" + supplies[i] + "</li>";
}
someVar += "</ul>";
```